# Solve the complex of inverse cosine of $i$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

## I was asked to solve $\cos^{-1}i$.

I take $\arccos(i) = z$
then $\cos(z) = \cos(x+iy)$
$ \cos(x+iy) = \cos(x)\cos(iy) - \sin(x)\sin(iy)$
$\cos(x)\cos(iy) - \sin(x)\sin(iy) = i$

this is where I stuck cause I can't separate the equation into real and imaginary value

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $z=\arccos(i)\implies\cos z=i$

$\implies\sin z=\pm\sqrt2$

$\implies e^{iz}=\cos z+i\sin z=?$

Alternatively,

$i=\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}2\implies e^{iz}=?$

Comment: why do we need to change it into polar form?